# Why @ (at) pop in my PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet formula?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I put this formula in my cell :

```php
     $worksheet->setCellValue("B6", '=MIN(IF(D9:D157>0,D9:D157))');  
     $worksheet->getStyle("B6")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DMYSLASH);
```

And the result when i open my file is :

```
=MIN(IF(@D9:D157>0;D9:D157))
```

Dont know why is putting an @ in the formula.
This @ break the formula. When i remove it is ok.
Do you have an idea ?
Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with different version of Excel.
I change my formula to a less complex one.